# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params.eventId')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to navigate from one screen using Drawer to another in react native by carrying a id from one screen to the other however, i am getting the above error. While navigating from stack screen it everything works properly but while navigation same screen from Drawer I am getting error. Drawer navigation is nested inside Stack navigation

// EventList.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Pressable, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import color from "../../app/color";
import variables from "../../app/variables";
import { EVENT_DATA } from "../../data/category-data";

function EventList({}) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {EVENT_DATA.map((event) => {
        function onPressHandler() {
          navigation.navigate("CategoryOverviewScreen", {
            eventId: event.id,
          });
        }

        const eventBlock = [styles.eventBox];

        if (event.id === "e7") {
          eventBlock.push(styles.flexEnd);
        }

        return (
          <View
            key={event.id}
            style={[
              eventBlock,
              {
                backgroundColor: event.color,
                width: event.width,
                height: event.height,
              },
            ]}
          >
            <Text style={styles.title}>{event.title}</Text>
            <Pressable onPress={onPressHandler} style={variables.linkButton}>
              {event.icon}
            </Pressable>
          </View>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}

export default EventList;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },

  eventBox: {
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
    marginBottom: 15,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: color.white,
    textAlign: "center",
    fontFamily: "robotoMedium",
  },
  flexEnd: {
    alignSelf: "flex-end",
  },
});
```

```
//CategoryOverviewScreen

import { useContext } from "react";
import { ScrollView } from "react-native";
import { CATEGORY_DATA, EVENT_DATA } from "../data/category-data";
import CategoryList from "../components/CategoryList";

function CategoryOverviewScreen({ route }) {
  const getEeventId = route.params.eventId;
  const displayedCategory = CATEGORY_DATA.filter((categoryData) => {
    return categoryData.eventId.indexOf(getEeventId) >= 0;
  });

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <CategoryList data={displayedCategory} />
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

export default CategoryOverviewScreen;
```

Comment: test with  eventId: '123',